# How do I insert a string into a hashmap that has an array as a map key?

Tags: c++, arrays, hashmap

I've been trying to insert a string into a hashmap called 'keys' that uses arrays as the key values. The commented out lines use a vector instead of an array as the key. When I use a vector instead of an array, the code works perfectly as intended. However, I want to find out if it's possible to use an array of a fixed size to solve the problem instead. If anyone can demonstrate how, I would greatly appreciate it!

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<vector<string>> groupAnagrams(vector<string>& strs) {
        vector<vector<string>> res;
        map<array<int,26>,vector<string>> keys;
      //  map<vector<int>,vector<string>> keys; 
        for(auto x:strs){
            int count[26];
           // vector<int> count(26,0);
            for(auto c:x){
                count[c-'a']++;
            }
            keys[count].emplace_back(x);
        }
          for(auto k = keys.begin(); k != keys.end(); k++){
                res.emplace_back(k->second);
            }
        return res;
    }
};
```

Here's the error I get:

```
Line 13: Char 17: error: no viable overloaded operator[] for type 'map<array<int, 26>, vector<std::string>>' (aka 'map<array<int, 26>, vector<basic_string<char>>>')
            keys[count].emplace_back(x);
            ~~~~^~~~~~
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_map.h:490:7: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'int [26]' to 'const std::map<std::array<int, 26>, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>>>, std::less<std::array<int, 26>>, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::array<int, 26>, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>>>>>>::key_type' (aka 'const std::array<int, 26>') for 1st argument
      operator[](const key_type& __k)
      ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_map.h:510:7: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'int [26]' to 'std::map<std::array<int, 26>, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>>>, std::less<std::array<int, 26>>, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::array<int, 26>, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>>>>>>::key_type' (aka 'std::array<int, 26>') for 1st argument
      operator[](key_type&& __k)
      ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: What doesn't work about array? What specific error do you get?

Comment: 3 notes: 1)You forgot to initialize your `count` array to contain all 0's; 2)maps require unique keys. std::multimap allows duplicate keys, 3)std::map is a tree implementation. std::unordered_map is the hash version.

Comment: And for the actual issue which you are trying to solve:  your map has a key type of array<int,26>, but you have declared count as a "raw" array. `int count[26];` ==> `std::array<int, 26> count = {0};`. A default comparator exists for this for std:map.

Comment: @AviBerger Can you elaborate or demonstrate to me what you mean? I just started coding in C++ a couple days ago.

Comment: @AviBerger Never mind, I see what you mean. I guess my next question is this. Is it possible to use a "raw" array as a map key?

Comment: It's possible to use a raw array. It's easier to use a `std::array<int, 26>`. Declare `std::array<int, 26> count;` and use it just like you use it now.

Comment: @JohnFilleau I used the `std::array<int, 26>` and I can confirm it worked. How would I use a "raw" array?

Comment: Using a raw array would be trickier due to something called "Array-to-pointer decay". I don't see any benefit to trying that here. I'd stay with std::array for this.

Comment: @AviBerger Should I always use `std::array<int, x>` instead of a raw array then? Or are there cases in which a raw array is more beneficial?

Comment: Actually, really do stay with std::array. I don't think there is a viable good way to do this with raw arrays. The most obvious approaches won't work or will have object lifetime issues that will make it fragile., Next approach that I can think of essentially recreates std::array.

Comment: For arrays with sizes known at compile time, I'd suggest sticking with std::array. When sizes aren't known until run time, std::array won't work and std::vector comes into play. Times you might deal with raw arrays are when you are experienced and have to implement something like std::vector; sometimes when dealing with an interface that needs raw arrays; and if you are coding in a situation where use of std::vector is prohibited or nearly so.

Comment: I played around, and it turns out you CAN NOT use a raw array as a map key. You can use a pointer, you can use a comparator that you template on the size. But then at that point you're trusting the users of the map to only pass in correctly sized arrays. Use `std::array`. https://godbolt.org/z/5YdPEsjPv

Comment: @JohnFilleau In addition to that, the actual data of the key is not what the map contains, so you also have to trust the users to maintain that data outside the map for the lifetime of the map. And not in something like a vector that might reallocate and change the address of things. A virtually guaranteed mess. So even being clever and using an `int p [1][26];` isn't going to save you.

Comment: Thank you both for your insights and information! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

For std::map, you need to implement `<` less than comparator to make it work for key insertion. So probably a free function like `bool operator <(const auto &array1, const auto &array2)` with your logic on sorting the arrays should make the insertion work.
Might also need to provide equality (==) overload (but can not remember if it is required or not) for retrieval.

Answer (score 0):

is also defined as one of the less-than operators which we can use in , so its quite simple to use them. You should consider the way how you are trying to access or assign the map.Here's an example for your convenience.

> Blockquote
> map<array<int,26>,string> ex;
> ex[{{4,5,6}}] = "whatever";